# Correct way to declare a method with two type parameters in inheritance hierarchy

Tags: java, generics, covariance, contravariance, method-declaration

When writing a method that takes two objects, with two type parameters in a subtype-supertype relation, what is the best way of declaring your intentions out of these options?

1. Declare both `super` and `extends`:

   ```
   public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<? extends T> src) { ... }
   ```
2. Declare just the `extends`:

   ```
   public static <T> void copy(List<T> dst, List<? extends T> src) { ... }
   ```
3. Declare just the `super`:

   ```
   public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<T> src) { ... }
   ```

From my understanding, all three are correct, and are equivalent to each other, as all you're interested in is the relative inheritance of the type arguments of `dst` and `src`. So which is better?

Comment: Which do you consider to be simpler and easier to understand?

Comment: as you say "inheritance instance" so use a 2 way to declare.

Comment: Why is that better than specifying one `extends` or `super`?

Answer (score 1):

I think extends is most common and if there is no need to use both you shouldn't. So I'd go with extends only.

So there is not a correct way, unless you have a convention that specifies it.